# Authorize attribute in MVC doesn't redirect when user isn't logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have my own authentication which looks like this in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie == null || authCookie.Value == "")
        return;

    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket;

    try
    {
        authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }

    string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(';');

    if (Context.User != null)
        Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
}
```

And then in Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Users/Login" defaultUrl="~/Items/Index" timeout="432000" />
</authentication>
```

It can authorize fine. I've tested it by accessing the page without logging in and writing: 
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
which will return false. Manually going to ~/Users/Login and logging in will then cause it to return true. So the authentication works, it just doesn't redirect users who are not logged in to the ~/Items/Index page. I have the [Authorize] attribute on the controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
```

Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

Comment: Do you have `[AllowAnonymous]` on the `Index()` method?

Comment: What does your login method do? You probably want to be calling `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` or similar.

Comment: have you tried deleting cookies in the browser before testing? smells like you might have old cookie setup which makes all your requests authorized already.

Comment: No, I have no [AllowAnonymous] anywhere. It's also not an issue with cookies, I've tried it in different browsers and in incognito and it's still the same results.

Comment: I just tried creating an entirely new project and doing a simple a login there and it works fine, so I must have some sort of conflict in my original project that breaks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. It turned out that the NinjectWebCommon file was the one causing it. I simply removed it and it works again.